# Windbg: How to set breakpoint on one of the overloads of a C++ function?

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

I have two overloads of a c++ function and I would like to set a breakpoint on one of them:

```
0:000> bu myexe!displayerror
Matched: 00000000`ff3c6100 myexe!displayError (int, HRESULT, wchar_t *)
Matched: 00000000`ff3c60d0 myexe!displayError (int, HRESULT)
Ambiguous symbol error at 'myexe!displayerror'
```

Heck I would be fine with setting breakpoints on all overloads, but can't seem to figure out how:

```
0:000> bu myexe!displayerror*
Matched: 00000000`ff3c6100 myexe!displayError (int, HRESULT, wchar_t *)
Matched: 00000000`ff3c60d0 myexe!displayError (int, HRESULT)
Ambiguous symbol error at 'myexe!displayerror*'
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
bu 0xff3c6100
```

If I remember right, WinDbg allows setting breakpoints by address too.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried "bm myexe!displayerror*" ?

Answer (score 3):

```
bm myexe!displayerror
```

This will set breakpoints all all overloads, than you use `bc` to clear the ones you don't want

```
bc 1-3
```

Or just disable them

```
bd 1-3
```

The problem with `bm` is that the breakpoints it produces will sometimes fail to be evaluate and trigger a break. Annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

bp @@( MyClass::MyMethod ) break on methods (useful if the same method is overloaded and thus present on several addresses)

Answer (score 1):

Search your dll for all entry point matching your symbol

```
x myexe!displayerror
```

this will output all symbols matching the search string and their entry points, then set the breakpoint on the address

```
bp ff3c6100 // for myexe!displayError (int, HRESULT, wchar_t *)
```

This will set a specific breakpoint when that address is hit, or you set bp against the other address. You can set the breakpoint to just hit once, clear the breakpoint and exit

```
bp /1 ff3c6100
```

and you can also execute commands such as dump the call stack, variables and continue:

```
bp ff3c6100 "kb;dv;g"
```

You may also just open your source code when WinDbg is attached, navigate to the line of code you want to set the breakpoint on and hit F9 (same as you would do using Visual Studio), it will pause for a while before setting a breakpoint at that line, this assumes you have access to the source code.